# std::stoi - String with non-numeric characters getting parsed as an integer without throwing exception (c++)

Tags: c++, parsing, integer, std

When using std::stoi and passing a string which begins with a number and is followed by non-numeric characters, the string is parsed successfully as an integer, without throwing an exception.
E.g "0abcf" is parsed as 0.
I want a string to be parsed as an integer only if it contains numeric characters exclusively (i.e "123" but not "12a"), is there an existing function that does this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on stoi? You can pass a pointer as the second argument which will return back appropriately if the string is not entirely an integer. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: Related: [atoi() accepting strings mixed with number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74493493/514235)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

> `int       stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );`
>   ...
>   the index of [the first unconverted] character will be calculated and stored in `*pos`, giving the number of characters that were processed by the conversion.

Thus, all you need to do in order to check whether all characters were valid/parsed is to pass a second argument, then check whether this value (the number of converted characters) is equal to the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem but requires an extra check. I was hoping for a parse function which throws an exception even in such cases as "0ab"

Comment: @D.Fonkaz -- you have all the information you need to write the parse function that you want.

Comment: The quoted text omits an important part: it only does that if `pos` is not a null pointer. Upvoted.

Comment: I could write a parse function from scratch also. it's just better to use standard library functions, when available..

Comment: `int parseInt(const std::string &s) { std::size_t pos; int result = std::stoi(s, &pos); if (pos != s.size()) throw std::runtime_error("can't parse integer"); return result; }`