# atoi() accepting strings mixed with number

Tags: c, c-strings, atoi, strtol

For a task I need use `if atoi(INPUT) == 0` to check that a users input is a valid integer and not 0. The problem is when I enter any string that starts with an integer, it is automatically accepted, even if there are non-integer characters after the integer, for example "1aaaabcc" is accepted.

I understand that atoi() is in the example I just stated, would take the 1 and ignore it, but theortically this should be wrong input from the user since it is not a valid integer. Would there be something to add to my code (without adding any libraries) or change something with atoi to fix this?

Please let me know if you need sample code in case its not clear.

Comment: You should not use `atoi` anyway. Use `strtol`, it can tell you where it stopped parsing.

Comment: The problem with `atoi` is that it provides no easy method of handling an error. If you use [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) you can use the end pointer to check if the entire string was consumed or not. You could also validate the string you have to verify it is all digits before calling `atoi`.

Comment: unfortunately in the task given I am only allowed to use `atoi`

Answer (score 4):

The function `atoi` is an "alias" for this function call

```
atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
```

So in your case you should use the function `strtol` and pass the second argument unequal to `NULL` that points to a pointer. In this case you can check whether the pointer points to the end of the corresponding string.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *endptr;

    int n = ( int )strtol( "A", &endptr, 10 );

    printf( "n = %d, *endptr = %d\n", n, *endptr );

    n = ( int )strtol( "10A", &endptr, 10 );

    printf( "n = %d, *endptr = %d\n", n, *endptr );

    n = ( int )strtol( "10", &endptr, 10 );

    printf( "n = %d, *endptr = %d\n", n, *endptr );
}
```

Its output is

```
n = 0, *endptr = 65
n = 10, *endptr = 65
n = 10, *endptr = 0
```

As you can see only in the third call of the function `strtol` the pointer `endptr` points to the terminating zero character `'\0'`. In all preceding calls it points to the letter `'A'` that has the ASCII code `65`.

You can also accept or deny strings like for example `"10   "`. If to accept such a string then in this case you need to check that the tail of the string contains only white space characters.

You should attentively read the description of the function `strtol`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, I am only limited to using `atoi` for the given task but I'll definitely use this in the future.

Comment: @kimmy If you are using only atoi then you need  to check whether the passed string contains only digits.

Answer (score 0):

`aoti()` is useful for quick and dirty code but not up to the task for robust error handling.

Non-integer characters after the integer, as in `"1aaaabcc"` is best detected with `strtol()`.

With `strtol()`, we can detect more.

1. Out of range for an `int` like `"12345678901234567890"`, but not the same length `"00000000000000000001"`.
2. Allow non-integer characters after the integer when text is all white-space.  This is reasonable as `strtol()/atoi()` accept optional leading white-space.  It also allows passing an entire  *line* of input like `"1234\n"`.
3. No conversion as in `"asd"`, `"   "`, `""`.

I recommend a helper function

```
// Return true on success    
bool convert_string_to_int(int *dest, const char *s) {
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;  // Gets updated to point to the end of the conversion.
  long lvlaue = strtol(s, &endptr, 0);
  if (s == endptr) {
    *dest = 0;
    return false;  // No conversion
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE || lvalue < INT_MIN || lvalue > INT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    *dest = lvalue < 0 ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX; 
    return false;  // Out of range.
  }
  *dest = (int) lvalue;
  if (errno) {
    return false;  // Implementation specific errors like s == NULL
  }
  while (isspace(*((unsigned char *)endptr))) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) {
    return false;  // Junk at the end.
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, I am only limited to using `atoi` for the given task but I'll definitely use this in the future.