# Sanity Checking in C

Tags: c, if-statement

So I need to sanity check the int n and it must be a number that is higher than zero so I have"

```
    n = strtol(argv[1], &ptr, 10);
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nthe number should be a positive integer\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

But I also need to make it not accept an input with letters like for example 53e

Can someone help?

I tried isdigit() but I don't really know how to use it properly

Comment: Did you read the [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) manual? It even has example code on how to check for various errors and invalid inputs.

Comment: You probably need to loop over every character in `argv[1]` and pass it into the [isdigit function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm). If it ever returns 0, you know you've found an unwanted character

Comment: @kaylum - as they say 'if all else fails, read the manual'

Comment: There are multiple possible checks: 1) conversion success `argv[1] == ptr`? 2) `errno == ERANGE` (`long` overflow) 3) trailing junk 4) In `int` range 5) other `errno` due to `argv[1] == NULL`.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74493962/2410359)